# How does the yii2 Controller action injection works

Tags: php, dependency-injection, yii2

I am working on the Dependency Injection of yii2 and I find some really useful topic,the [Controller action injection](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-di-container.html#controller-action-injection). I tried, but it just does not work. I have done all the google thing and event read the source code of the yii2 framework, am I missing something?
Here is my code:

```
//my action
public function actionIndex(JobService $jobService) {
    //logic code
}

//i register the dependencies in the bootstrap file
// and yes ,i tried \Yii::$container->set('JobService', '\hr\services\JobService') too
\Yii::$container->set('\hr\services\JobService', '\hr\services\JobService');
```

I got the error message below:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the controller DI just fixed two month ago, and they hadn't release yet, you can fix it manually.
check you yii\web\Controller with [github-yii\web\Controller](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/web/Controller.php)

Comment: It's really helpful,tks!

Comment: I'm really confused that why the yii offical write the feature into the document while the latest release still don't implementation it